# PHP-Apache mkdir permissions

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, server

At the moment i`m working on the upload part for my website.
I have 2 diffrent upload.php files which i call.
At the first php file i just:

```
mkdir($folderpath.$name);
chmod($folderpath.$name",777);
```

on the server the folder has 755 rights <--- it´s ok just that i can wirte in it with PHP

on my second upload.php i make:

```
mkdir($folderpath.$_POST['name']);
chmod($folderpath.$_POST['name'], 777);
```

on the server the folder has 411 rights

just why ?? both php files has same permissions and are in the same subfolder

Comment: 1. _never_ use client side provided data for server side file system operations! The client can specify _anything_ an attacker might feel happy to!

Comment: 2. the final permissions depend on the `umask` that is set in the environment of the proces executing the http server process. The permission you specify is filtered by that `umask` pattern: http://php.net/manual/de/function.umask.php

Comment: okey the premissions depends on the permissons form the webserver process right ? so why does he craete 1 folder with 755 and th eother one with 441

Comment: Kind of. To be precise: that process inherits an environment setup by the launching process. That environment defines many things, one of those is said `umask`. That is what you are interested in. Did you read the documentation I linked? It explains all you need to know...

Comment: Yes i read it already today morning but it didn´t worked. Now it worked dont know why (server-restart or browser cache maybe). Thank you